# FFmpeg MOV to MP4, do I also need .OGG , .WEBM files too?

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video

I am new to FFmpeg and I'm just getting started. I have the two following commands to take a `.mov` upload and downsize it and save it out as an `.mp4`. I also produce a thumbnail version of the same.

What I am doing here seems to work well and I manage to get the `.mov` file from 12.5mb to about a 1mb `.mp4`.

My question from here is, can I get away with only providing a `.mp4` for the source video, or do I need to provide additional `.ogg` and/or `.webm` files too? An if so, how is that best achieved? Would I have to loop that FFmpeg command again to output new `.ogg` and `.webm` files?

`exec("ffmpeg -i src.mov -ss 00 -to 60 -vf scale=700:-1 -crf 30 -an -movflags +faststart output.mp4");`

`exec("ffmpeg -i src.mov -ss 00 -to 10 -vf 'scale=128:128:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase, crop=128:128' -crf 30 -an tn_output.mp4");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I get away with only providing a .mp4 for the source video, or do I need to provide additional .ogg and/or .webm files too?

I'm not that well-versed in webdev, but you'd like to have your `<video>` content to have multiple sources for browser compatibility. IIRC, Chromium does not natively support mp4, for example.

> An if so, how is that best achieved? Would I have to loop that FFmpeg command again to output new .ogg and .webm files?

FFmpeg can produce multiple video files at once from one source:

```
ffmpeg -i src.mov -ss 00 -to 60 \
  -filter_complex [v:0]scale=700:-1,split=3[v1][v2][v3] \
  -map [v1] output.mp4 \
  -map [v2] output.webm \
  -map [v3] output.egg
```

You need to use `split` filter to copy the video streams as one stream can only be used by one output file.

What I do not know for sure is whether this is faster than calling FFmpeg 3 times (most likely, but never tried it myself).